# Trying to do a PG dump from an active rails server and getting password authentication failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pg-dump

I am trying to run this command

`ssh -p <PORT> <user@server> 'PGPASSWORD=\"<production_password>\" pg_dump -U database_user #<production_database> -h 127.0.0.1 -F t' > <location>`

and I am getting

`pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "database_name" failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "database_user"`

The credentials must be right since deploys work fine.

This is a RoR app on CentOS running live, and I was trying to follow other stack overflow answers and realized I do not have directories `var/lib/postgres` nor do I have `/etc/postgresql`. I was looking for `/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/pg_hba.conf`

I do not imagine postgres was not installed, since we are actively running a postgres database.

All I want is to dump the rails pg production database to my local computer!

Any leads would be super helpful.

-------Adding my database.yml config--------

```
adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  host: 127.0.0.1
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  reconnect: true
  timeout: 5000
```

Another note to add to the puzzle, we have 2 or 3 PG databases on this same server.

AND using `this_is_a_fake_db_name` still threw me the same error. So it definitely is not connecting to the database I'm requesting.

Comment: you might be connecting to the wrong database as rails append env at the end of database names like database_development or database_test etc.

Comment: If you `ssh` in normally first, and then run `pg_dump` separately, do you get the same error?

Comment: Given you can't find the relevant Postgres directories, are you sure that's the DB host?  Perhaps that's the web server and the DB is running on a different server?

Comment: You tell pg_dump to connect as "postgres", but the error message says 'failed for user "database_user"'.  I wouldn't expect this to be possible.

Comment: Thanks for all the input! I will try through SSH now jared-beck. That's the host saved in the rails database.yml along with the rest of the creds, and it's def on this server. We have only one bill-doughty. Sorry jjanes that was a typo when I was trying to replace my keys, but I am sure it is the same user. I edited the original message.

Comment: @JaredBeck I got the same error inside the server. :(

Comment: @ArsiiRasheed Tried removing the _production at the end and got the same error. This makes me wonder if it's even connecting to any db, and maybe it is the host address, but unsure how I can test that.

Comment: Given that the error says "password authentication failed", I'd recommend reading docs section [20.5. Password Authentication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/auth-password.html). Might want to read other parts of chapter 20 too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I was blocked from connecting to my database and that is why I could not pass authentication.

In the end I backed it up as sudo on the server:
`(su postgres -c 'pg_dump -U postgres <db-name>') > <backupNAME>.sql`

Then copied it down with SCP

`scp -P <port> user@server:/path/to/<backupNAME>.sql <local/path/to/save>`

Thanks @lackoftactics for your help!